# Creating a block in own module

Tags: 6, blocks

I am using Drupal 6.27, created my own module, used hook_perm() in my module. Now the question is - did i do that in the right way?

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_block().
 */

function adminka_block($op = 'list', $delta = 0, $edit = array()) {
  switch($op) {
    case 'list':
      return array(
        'adminka_simple_block' => array('info' => 'adminka simple block', 'cache' => BLOCK_NO_CACHE),
      );
    case 'view':
      switch($delta) {
        case 0:
          if (user_access('view adminka')) {
            $block['subject'] = t('My admin panel');
            $block['content'] = '<a href="/node/add/' . variable_get('content_type', false) . '">Добавить ' . variable_get('content_type_name', false) . '</a><br />';
            $block['content'] .= '<a href="/logout">Выход</a>';
            break;
          }
      }
      return $block;
  }
}
```

Because i didn't found another way to restrict that block visiblity only to users with user_acess('view adminka').

Answer (score 1):

I think you do it  in  the right way, but instead of using this

```
$block['content'] = '<a href="/node/add/' . variable_get('content_type', false) . '">Добавить ' . variable_get('content_type_name', false) . '</a><br />';
$block['content'] .= '<a href="/logout">Выход</a>';
```

you should use [l function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/6)

> This function correctly handles aliased paths, and adds an 'active'
>   class attribute to links that point to the current page (for theming),
>   so all internal links output by modules should be generated by this
>   function if possible.

like this:

```
$block['content'] .= l(t('Выход'), '/logout');
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding perms, yes, you are doing that part right.  However, I *think* the `$delta` case value in your view should be `adminka_simple_block` not `0` and this is why I like to set up blocks like this instead because of the ease of adding more as your module gets bigger....

```
function adminka_block($op = 'list', $delta = 0, $edit = array()) {

  $blocks=array();

  switch($op) {

    case 'list':

      $blocks['admin']['info'] = 'adminka admin block';
      $blocks['admin']['cache'] = BLOCK_NO_CACHE;

      $blocks['another']['info'] = 'adminka another block';

      return $blocks;

    case 'view':

      switch($delta) {

        case 'admin':

          if (user_access('view adminka')) {

            $blocks['subject']  = t('My admin panel');
            $blocks['content']  = l('Добавить ' . variable_get('adminka_content_type_name', NULL), 'node/add/' . variable_get('adminka_content_type', NULL));
            $blocks['content'] .= l('Выход', 'logout');

          }

          return $blocks;

        case 'another':

          $blocks['subject']  = t('Another Block');
          $blocks['content']  = 'Here we have another block';
          $blocks['content'] .= ' with more content, etc...';
          $blocks['content'] .= ' with default caching.';

          return $blocks;

      }
   }
}
```

I will admit I am *not* up on translation stuff, but I think you may want to think about using `t()` to do more here, but that's a whole nother ball of wax :)